# Why Java frameworks do not enforce use of interfaces?

Tags: java, architecture, frameworks

I was just wondering, why there is no interface for a Spring Bean or for a EJB Bean (or for an OSGi service)? I know that there is no need for this because frameworks can use reflection API for calling methods but wouldn't it be less erroneus if interfaces were used instead?

For example, why there is no interface for OSGi component which would look like this:

```
interface OSGIComponent {
  void activate(BundleContext context);
  ... 
}
```

Comment: Which methods would you put on the interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of Spring, you don't have to implement a Spring-specific interface to be able to use Spring with your code. This is actually seen as an advantage: it prevents your code being tied to Spring, therefore making it more portable.

That's not to say that you can't implement Spring-specific interfaces. One example that springs to mind (no pun intended) is [`InitializingBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html); this defines a method, [`afterPropertiesSet()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html#afterPropertiesSet%28%29), which gets called (as the name suggests) after Spring has instantiated your bean and set all of its properties.

So there are often framework-specific interfaces and classes that you can use; you have to balance keeping your code portable with making use of the useful stuff that frameworks provide.

You gave the example of an OSGi component that might implement an `OSGIComponent` interface.  Spring does in fact have an interface that your class can implement to be passed a reference to the containing Spring context: [`ApplicationContextAware`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html). Typically, though, you  don't need to make use of these framework-specific interfaces. Your code is generally easier to understand if it just focuses on the actual business logic, rather than details of how the framework is instantiating objects, wiring objects together, and so on.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that it might be seen as a disadvantage as well (please see my comment under Michael's answer). And I don't get this argument of portability: if you base your code on Spring, it will not work without Spring, so it has to depend on Spring anyway.

Comment: I think you may put your comment to @michael-borgwardt answer in your answer as well, as it seems to be even better rationale.

Answer (score 2):

> I was just wondering, why there is no interface for a Spring Bean
>   or for a EJB Bean (or for an OSGi service)?

Before version three, the EJB standard *did* "enforce use of interfaces". In fact, you had to have at least two, often three interfaces for each bean (Home, Remote and Local). Except the implementation classes didn't implement those interfaces and you had to have an XML deployment descriptor that connected everything together and if anything didn't fit (e.g. because of a typo) you got a completely cryptic runtime error. It was an absolute nightmare, and EJBs have a horrible reputation to this day, even though this mistake was fixed years ago.

> I know that there is no need for this because frameworks can use reflection API for calling methods

That makes no sense at all.

> but wouldn't it be less erroneus if interfaces were used instead?

Interfaces aren't magic fairy dust that makes code "less erroneous". If you have an API that may have several implementations, you create an interface. Otherwise you don't. That's it.

Comment: When OSGi container wants to notify a component that it became active, it uses reflection to call its `activate` method. If, for example, the name of the method is misspelled, it will be only detected at runtime. If there was an interface for an OSGi component, this bug would be detected during compilation.

Comment: Methods defined in an interface are implicitly `public`. If `activate` were defined in an interface, and your component implemented that interface, its `activate` method would also be `public`. However it's not desirable for such a method to be part of a component's public API.

Answer (score 0):

If the beans have to implement an interface, that interface must be present in the classpath, causing the bean to depend on the dependency injection framework in use (at least prior to the standardization of dependency injection annotations in JSR-330, and now we want backwards compatibility).

However, in Spring, beans *may* implement an interfaces to interact with the container, for instance `InitializingBean` and `DisposableBean`. ([source](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle))

Comment: I understand that the framework would have to be in the classpath but what is wrong with this? Why do we want to avoid this?